# MVVM e Binding para diferentes classes

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp

Se no padrão Model View ViewModel eu tenho:

> - MainPageModel.cs
> - MainPageViewModel.cs
> - MainPage.cs
> - MainPage.xaml

`MainPage.cs` também é parte da minha camada *View*? Se sim, é nela que devo delegar a responsabilidade da **"interatividade visual"** da `MainPage.xaml`?
Como ocultar **elementos ou métodos que só tenham função visual**, por exemplo?

Se sim, como faço para dentro da `MainPage.xaml` dar um *Binding* direcionado a uma função da `MainPage.cs`? Considerando que dentro da `MainPage.xaml` eu tenho um `Page.DataContext` que faz **toda *Binding* ir por padrão** para a `MainPageViewModel.cs`

Comment: Veja se consegue esclarecer suas dúvidas aqui: http://netcoders.com.br/blog/introducao-ao-mvvm/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por padrão, quando você cria um elemento visual (Window, page, usercontrol) são criados dois arquivos conectados. Um é o .xaml e o outro o .cs. O ".cs" é o chamado 'code-behind' que é nada mais que o arquivo completo de código do elemento visual, no construtor desse código há uma chamada de método para "InitializeComponent()" que nada mais é do que a leitura do arquivo .xaml e a transformação dele em arquivo C#. Agora, respondendo as perguntas.

1 - Sim, o arquivo MainPage.cs é parte da view, pois ele é o code-behind desse elemento.

2 - Depende de como você está trabalhando. O code-behind já tem acesso nativo a todos os controles da view que voce declarou o "x:Name". Sendo assim, utilizar esse arquivo para somente delegar funções para a view-model é válido no MVVM, mas utilizar ele para a logica da UI não é MVVM.

3 - Para ocultar o controle no code-behind, basta somente retirar a tag "x:Name" do controle no arquivo xaml. Métodos que só tenham função visual podem ser utilizados no code-behind, seria o exemplo de animações que podem ser um pouco complexas no código xaml.

4 - Você não precisa dar um Binding para elementos do Code-Behind, basta utilizar o "x:Name" e você será capaz de acessa-lo.

O padrão MVVM é exatamente esse, utilizar o DataContext para conectar a View-Model (que terá a logica de funcionalidade da view) através dos Bindings. Como prática do pattern, aconselho fortemente a mantar a logica nas view-models e se precisar de métodos visuais como animações, ai você pode deixar no code-behind.